# VS2019 - Sudo Remote Debugging on Linux with Cmake project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have a cmake c++ Linux project that is using Remote Debugging from a windows computer. The program accesses the GPIO pins on Raspberry pi so it needs to run under sudo on the remote machine. Everything is building and working but it crashes on the first line that needs admin access.  I have not been able to figure out how to launch the newly compiled application under sudo. I have tried different settings in the launch_schema.json but no luck so far.

Answer (score -1):

I found this and it worked for me.
[Unable to launch debugger (gdb) with root permissions.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/861)

Basically you decorate the existing gdb binary on the Pi with a bash script and then use the script.
The steps on the Pi are:

```
cd /usr/bin

sudo mv gdb gdborig
```

Now create a bash script named gdb with following content.

```
sudo nano gdb
```

Content of the bash is;

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo gdborig $@
```

Finally, make the script runnable with.

```
sudo chmod 0755 gdb
```

Thanks goes to Buğra Aydoğar